# Is it possible to only render a small region for compositing?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have a 4K render of a simulation. I would like to composite the time for each frame on top of this render. The time to be rendered is a very small region, so I'd like to just crop that region to render and composite it. However, when using render regions, the output even with compositing is the same size.

Desired outcome
[image]

with render region

[image]

Is it possible to keep the rest of the image in the compositor without also cropping that?

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you bypass the composite and go straight to a File Output node it behaves as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can mix image and render with a node setup like this:

[image]

Comment: That's not it :/ If I choose 'Viewer Node' while look at the render it doesn't crop the composite. Do you know how to save the viewer node image for an animation instead of the composite?

Comment: If you have troubles with composite node, probably you should re-render scene, and compositing should be updated.